# T.Test across several columns at once?

Tags: r, t-test

I'm attempting to do a T-Test across many different columns at once, but can't figure out how to do it. Here is what I have for one of the columns, `Clout`.

```
t.test(wf[wf$ThreadID == 249001,]$Clout,wf[wf$ThreadID == 230005,]$Clout)
```

But I have about 20 other columns, e.g. `Authentic`, `Tone`

How can I run this test across all columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following.

```
n <- ncol(wf)
inx1 <- which(wf$ThreadID == 249001)
inx2 <- which(wf$ThreadID == 230005)
ttest_list <- lapply(seq_len(n), function(j) t.test(wf[inx1, j], wf[inx2, j]))
```

Note: How can you be sure that there are as many elements such that `wf$ThreadID == 249001` and `wf$ThreadID == 230005`?

Comment: I've ended up using `sapply(c("Clout","Tone","Authentic"), function(j) t.test(wf[inx1, j], wf[inx2, j]))`

Comment: If those are the only columns you want, then yes, it seems it works. Sorry if I misunderstood the question. As for the use of `sapply`, note that it will make no difference, the resulting list is exactly the same.

Comment: I wanted all the columns but at least one of the columns wasn't working so it all didn't run.

Comment: @Sam What error did it throw? Are all the columns numeric?